CORS and x-apikey are mutual exclusive?
This is my angular service method:
public getAllItems() : Observable<Product[]> {
    
    const options: HttpOptions = {
      url: "http://yyyy",
      headers: {
        'x-apikey': 'xxx',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      webFetchExtra: { mode: 'no-cors', credentials: 'include' }
    };

    return from(CapacitorHttp.get(options).then(res => res.data as Product[]));
}

As I am running it locally and requesting external web service for API call, I've disabled cors. But whenever cors is disabled, x-apikey is not sent. If I enable cors the x-apikey is sent, however due to cors I've got an error. Are cors and x-apikey key mutually exclusive somehow?


Are cors and x-apikey key mutually exclusive somehow?

CORS is mandatory for it. It's no-cors that it is mutually exclusive with.
Setting a HTTP request header (with the exception of safe headers and forbidden headers) requires that the browser sends a preflight OPTIONS request to the server asking for permission and that the server responds with suitable Access-Control headers to grant that permission.
Setting no-cors mode tells the browser to not ask for permission and, instead, silently drop anything that would require it (this also includes credentials).

Good answer, but can you please clarify the bit about credentials? Fetch does allow no-cors credentialed requests...

@jub0bs — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#including_credentials — Without no-cors mode:  It will allow the request if the request is simple (which this one isn't) and block the response if permission isn't granted. If the request isn't simple then it will require a preflight. If no-cors is set then it will silently ignore credentials: 'include'.

You write: If no-cors is set then it will silently ignore credentials: 'include'. Have you checked that this is indeed the case? It's not. Neither that MDN page nor the Fetch standard itself say anything of the sort.
